# How to return to stdin/out after io-redirection in C

Tags: c, operating-system, io-redirection

I am creating a simple shell in C and one of the features is IO-redirection. However; I am having a hard time figuring out how to return to stdin/stdout after finishing execution of a redirection command.

I tried copying stdin/out and then using it again in the main function as shown in the code, but that did not work.

```
void  execute(char **args, bool flag)
{
    pid_t  pid;
    int status;
    int exc;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     
        printf("forking child process failed\n");
    }

    else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
        if(in_flag){
            file_desc_in = open(sub2, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);
            chmod(sub2 , S_IRWXU|S_IRGRP|S_IXGRP|S_IROTH);
            stdinCopy = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(file_desc_in, 0);
            close(file_desc_in);    
            in = true;

        }
        else if(out_flag){
            file_desc_out = open(sub2,O_WRONLY |O_APPEND | O_CREAT);
            chmod(sub2 , S_IRWXU|S_IRGRP|S_IXGRP|S_IROTH);
            stdoutCopy = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(file_desc_out, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(file_desc_out);           
            out = true;

        }
        exc =  execvp(args[0], args);     /* execute the command  */

        printf("exec failed!\n")
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE)

    }

    if(flag){
        pid_t childpid = wait(&status);
    }

}
```

this part is in main()

```
if(out){
        dup2(stdoutCopy,STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(stdoutCopy);
        out = false;    
    }
    else if(in){
        dup2(stdinCopy,STDIN_FILENO);
        close(stdinCopy);
        in = false; 
    }
```

For example when I redirect the output of the ls command to some file output.txt, redirection works and the output shows in the file, but then all output goes to the same file for all newly entered commands instead of showing on the terminal.

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: The test in `if(exc < 0){
            printf("Wrong command!\n");
            exit(0);
        }` (after `execvp()`) is superfluous.  If it is successful, `execvp()` does not return; it only returns on failure.  The error should be printed to `stderr` (not `stdout`), and it should probably include the name of the command that wasn't executed (`args[0]`) and the name of the shell as a prefix to the error message.  This is tangential to your main problem, though.

Comment: Normally, you resolve the main problem by not doing I/O redirection in the main shell — you leave it to sub-processes in some shape or form. If you think you must do it in the main shell, then you preserve the current standard input, output, error by duplicating them to descriptors that are unlikely to be used by the shell program (perhaps 128, 129, 130), and then arrange the I/O redirection, and then fork. Before executing, you close the saved descriptors as they should not be open in the child process — or mark them 'close on exec' (`fcntl()` and `FD_CLOEXEC`) to close them automatically.

Comment: And when you need to restore the original standard channels, you dup them again from the saved descriptors.  The process of using `dup()` or `dup2()` clears the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag on the target descriptor.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I updated the code a bit to reflect the first response. However; isn't my code essentially doing what you described or am I missing something?

Comment: It's rather hard to say what you're doing — but superficially, the `if (out)` block might be doing what's necessary if there's also a block that does `dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, stdoutCopy); out = true;` somewhere earlier, where `stdoutCopy` is appropriately initialized (or you use `stdoutCopy = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);` or whatever).  The `else if (in)` part is wrong; you should not have the `else` there. The input and output can be reset independently. However, having said all that, if the parent doesn't do redirection, there's no need for these shenanigans at all. But it depends on how your I/O works.